# DataMapper naming convention clashes with existing MySQL table 

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I am working on a MySQL table that is used by another program. What I want to do is to put up a web interface for this database with Sinatra and DataMapper. However, when I declare my property in the DataMapper model, I run into some problem with naming convention.

For example, the field in MySQL table is ControlStationID, and I declared as such, but when DataMapper runs, it change it to control_station_id. Anyway I can rectify this? I can't change the table structure.

Thanks.

Error seen:

```
DataObjects::SQLError: Unknown column 'control_station_id' in 'field list' (code: 1054, sql state: 42S22, query: SELECT `id`, `control_station_id` FROM `returnmessage` ORDER BY `id`)
```

MySQL table structure

```
mysql> show fields from returnmessage;

+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ControlStationID  | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My code

```
class ReturnMessage
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :ID,                  Serial
  property :ControlStationID,     Integer

end

repository(:default).adapter.resource_naming_convention = lambda do |value|
  value.downcase
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
property :ControlStationID, Serial, :field=>'ControlStationID'
```